# Excel: How many times has a cell been referred to?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table of expenses in two columns (name, amount). I then created a list of categories and for each of those I summed the amounts of what I think is relevant to that category from the table of expenses.

At the end, to check I got all of it, I summed up all the amounts in each category and I found that I am a few hundred dollars short compared to the sum of all expenses in the expenses table.

I want to see which items in the expenses table has not yet been referred to in a =sum() function from my categories table. If there was a function that returns how many times a cell has been referred to in other functions, I will be able to easily identify such cells.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: The simplest method is,, select formula cell & press `F2`,, to find how may cell have been used,, or use Formula ,, `Precedence / Dependence` or better create Dynamic Named Range,, for each Category column,, so if  and when the new value been added,, Excel will automatically expand the SUM Range,,, also [Edit] the post and share screen Shot,, along with the Formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Conditional Formatting Rule based on a MATCH formula not matching will easily identify missing records. The following example uses this formula,

```
=ISNA(MATCH($B2, $F:$F, 0))
```

[image]